# CSS: fixed to bottom and centered

Tags: css, positioning, sticky-footer

I need my footer to be fixed to the bottom of the page and to center it. The contents of the footer may change at all time so I can't just center it via margin-left: xxpx; margin-right: xxpx;

The problem is that for some reason this doesn't work:

```
#whatever {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

I crawled the web and found nothing. I tried making a container div and nada. I tried other combinations and gurnisht. How can I make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not being centered? Or not being positioned at the bottom of the page? or both?

Comment: I can't make the one happen without the other. If both rules are written it will stick to the bottom but also to the left.

Comment: I know that this is an old post.  But there is a better way to do this.  Simply create the body with `position:relative` and a `padding` the size of the footer + the space between content and footer you want.  Then just make a footer div with an `absolute` and `bottom:0`.  Boom goes the dynamite.

Comment: I usually use Compass for this now.

Comment: @Michael, your comment should be an answer.  I wish I had seen it sooner.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should use a sticky footer solution such as this one :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

There are others like this;

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not 
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height 
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

html, body, #wrap {height: 100%;}

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

#main {padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/* CLEAR FIX*/
.clearfix:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
```

with the html:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main" class="clearfix">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thats not true. If you use fixed or absolute positioning, specifying only a bottom position will attach the element to the bottom. However, doing such a thing means that element is ALWAYS stuck to the bottom, no matter what. Sticky footer is the only way to get a footer to stick when the body is shorter than the viewport, and move down when it is taller.

Answer (score 49):

revised [code by Daniel Kanis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18008476/2743458):

just change the following lines in CSS

```
.problem {text-align:center}
.enclose {position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;}
```

and in html:

```
<p class="enclose problem">
Your footer text here.
</p>
```

Comment: bottom: 0 all i needed

Answer (score 26):

A jQuery solution

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        placeFooter();
    });
    placeFooter();
    // hide it before it's positioned
    $('#footer').css('display','inline');
});

function placeFooter() {    
    var windHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var offset = parseInt(windHeight) - parseInt(footerHeight);
    $('#footer').css('top',offset);
}

<div id='footer' style='position: fixed; display: none;'>I am a footer</div>
```

Sometimes it's easier to implement JS than to hack old CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLhEZ/

Answer (score 9):

The problem lies in `position: static`. Static means don't do anyting at all with the position. `position: absolute` is what you want. Centering the element is still tricky though. The following  should work:

```
#whatever {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

or

```
#whatever {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

But I recommend the first method.
I used centering techniques from this answer:
[How to center absolutely positioned element in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolute-element-in-div)

Comment: works properly.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a problem where the typical `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` didn't work. Discovered a neat functionality with `position: sticky`. Note it's "relatively" new so it won't with IE/Edge 15 and earlier.

Here's an example for w3schools.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est,  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dlerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dlerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dlerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dlerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas  dolor nteger frinegestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas </p>

<div class="sticky">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 potential issues that I see:

1 - IE has had trouble with position:fixed in the past. If you are using IE7+ with a valid doctype or a non-IE browser this isn't part of the problem

2 - You need to specify a width for the footer if you want the footer object to be centered. Otherwise it defaults to the full width of the page and the auto margin for the left and right get set to 0. If you want the footer bar to take up the width (like the StackOverflow notice bar) and center the text, then you need to add "text-align: center" to your definition.

Answer (score 3):

I have encased the 'problem div in another div' lets call this div the enclose div...
make the enclose div in css have a width of 100% and postion fixed  with a bottom of 0...
then insert the problem div into the enclose div this is how it would look

```
#problem {margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; /*what ever other styles*/}
#enclose {position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;}
```

then in html...

```
<div id="enclose">
    <div id="problem">
    <!--this is where the text/markup would go-->
    </div>
</div>
```

There ya go!
 
-**Hypertextie**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment from @Michael:

> There is a better way to do this. Simply create the body with
>   position:relative and a padding the size of the footer + the space
>   between content and footer you want. Then just make a footer div with
>   an absolute and bottom:0.

I went digging for the explanation and it boils down to this:

- By default, absolute position of bottom:0px sets it to the bottom of the window...not the bottom of the page.
- Relative positioning an element resets the scope of its children's absolute position...so by setting the body to relative positioning, the absolute position of bottom:0px now truly reflects the bottom of the page.

More details at http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using css grid.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
    height: 100%;
    display:grid;
    /*we divide the page into 3 parts*/
    grid-template-rows: 20px auto  30px;
    text-align: center;   /*this is to center the element*/ 
    
}

.container .footer{
    grid-row: 3;   /*the footer will occupy the last row*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">

        </div>
        <div class="content">

        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            here is the footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use css grid:a concrete example

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still seeking a solution for this, there’s a really simple way to do this:

```
.target-element {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

An important consideration is that because this sticks to the bottom of the window, it will cloak content scrolling behind it. So you’ll want to make sure it has a background color.

Also, you’ll want to give the parent some bottom padding that extends beyond the height of the fixed-position element. If `.target-element` is 4rem high, your bottom padding should be 4rem + the amount of space you want between the end of your scrolling content and the top of the fixed element.