# Create a fixed text at the bottom of multiple boxes using CSS

Tags: css, text, positioning

I am using CSS to align my text (which is just a "read more" link) at the bottom of my preview article boxes which have a standard height. The "read more" link now show up just below of the teaser text and I need to position it just a few pixels above the bottom line of the article box independently of the text height, like this

```
___________________________
|
|
|
|
|
|              read more >>
|___________________________
```

Can you please give me some ideas or examples ?

Regards,
George

Comment: Are your article boxes fixed sized?  I assume you're using `div`'s?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if I understand correctly, you want text at the bottom to be inside the preview box just above the bottom line rather than below it?  There's a trick for that, but it requires that you create an inner div without borders with a well-defined height (current height - 24px for example).  The outer div can have the border so it appears that the text is inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your article element to have `position:relative` and then set the **read more** link to have `position:absolute` so that you can position it within the article using the `bottom`/`right` css properties..

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/7bduy/

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. Thank you Gaby !!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Javascript in a long time, but right on the "Related" section there's a link that may help you: [CSS: fixed to bottom and centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123/css-fixed-to-bottom-and-centered)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into positioning the text relatively.

in css:

```
#selectorName{
    position:relative;
    left: 10px;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
}
```

this will allow you to move the link around in the box relative to the position where it's supposed to be according to document flow rules.

Answer (score 0):

If your article 'text' is fixed size, do something like this:

```
<div class="article">
<div class="readmore"><a href="#">read more ></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.article 
{
position relative;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
}
.readmore
{
position:absolute;
z-index:3;
width:50px;
height:25px;
right:0px;
top:280px;
}
```

...or something like that :)

Comment: The box that includes the text is fixed size, but the text may have 2 or 3 or 5 lines at most. The example showed above at example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/7bduy/ is what I really wanted. Thank you !