# CSS Footer Fixed Width, Bottom of screen, and centred

Tags: css, html, footer

I'm an iPhone Developer mainly, I'm a bit rubbish at CSS and I'm trying to make a webpage for my app.

I want to make my footer have the following properties:

- Fixed width of 640px
- Centered
- Attached to bottom of **screen**, not page. So when the user resizes the window, the footer is always at the bottom

All the other styling I can do myself, it's just positional styling that I find really difficult.

Can someone please explain to me how to do this in just CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a footer fixed in the page bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189238/how-to-make-a-footer-fixed-in-the-page-bottom)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
footer {
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0% -320px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0%;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/imisig/3

Example with heaps of text: http://jsbin.com/imisig/4

Comment: how would you modify the code to make it fluid 60%? just interested

Comment: You can use `width: 60%;` and `left: 20%;`, with no `margin` to do that. See http://jsbin.com/imisig/11

Answer (score 1):

Put the footer HTML into a `<div id="footer">`. And the CSS would be something like this:

```
#footer {
    width: 640px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px;
}
```

Explanation

- The `width` property sets the width to `640px`
- `position: fixed` will make it so it scrolls with the page
- `bottom: 0px` makes it fixed on the bottom of the page (distance to bottom = 0px)
- `left: 50%` puts the left side of the `div` to the center of the page
- `margin-left: -320px` - now we have to move it 320px from the left to make it centered

Comment: `margin` with `auto` doesn't work well with a `position` of `fixed`; the footer will be on the left of the screen. See my answer for an improved method.

Comment: Not a problem. `-310px` should be `-320px`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer{
 width:100%;

  position: fixed;

  bottom: 0%;
}
```

`position: fixed` will make it so it scrolls with the page

`bottom: 0px` makes it fixed on the bottom of the page (distance to bottom = 0px)

The `width` property sets the width to 100%