# cannot position a footer CSS

Tags: css, footer

I'm folowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189238/how-to-make-a-footer-fixed-in-the-page-bottom) tutorial for making a footer but the result is not as expected:

[image: Footer]

My html and css are in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLbwH/1/)

or below:

```
  <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="menuProfile">
                <div id="logotext">K-Panel &bull; Kerio Tools Management</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
    <div id="subheader">
        <div id="submenu" class="wrap">
            <div id="logocliente">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/"><img height="50"
                    id="logoIscrittoTestata"
                    src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/KPanel_logo_2014_58x224.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fix separatore"></div>
    <div id="page">

        <div id="right">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div></div>
<div id="footer">
        <strong>Freelands</strong> > Via Emilia Ponente, 479, 40132 Bologna (Italy) > Tel +39 051 7402558 > Fax +39 051 729153 > C.F. e P.IVA 03236491209 > <a
            id="footerEmailAzienda" href="mailto:info@freelands.it">info@freelands.it</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
background: transparent;
 }

 body {
font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, Tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 1;
text-align: center;
color: #404040;
 }

 html,body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
 }

 #container {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -50px;
 }

 #footer {
background-color: #0082C0;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-top: 15px;
 }

 * {
margin: 0;
 }

 body, html {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: calibri, gill sans, arial;
 }

 .wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -35px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
 }

 .footer, .push {
height: 35px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
 }

 #footer{
font-size: 12px;
font-family: calibri, gill sans, arial;
color: black;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
 }

 #header{
display:block;
clear:both;
margin-top:20px;
 }
```

Comment: If you're looking for help, why not state what it is that you're actually having a problem with?

Comment: You have a lot of wrappers going on. The first thing I would suggest is getting rid of some of those wrappers and containers that seem a bit extraneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `position:fixed;` to the footer to stay it fixed. To make it stay at the bottom, add a `bottom:0;`

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKm8k/)**

**The Code change:**

```
 #footer{
font-size: 12px;
font-family: calibri, gill sans, arial;
color: black;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: then add a `z-index` to make adjust it accordingly. - @Christoph

Comment: you misunderstood...there is actually no need for fixed position and z-indexing...

Comment: Okay, how can I phrase it correctly. Your solution uses `position:fixed`. This is bad. Don't do it. Got it now?

Comment: But the link that he has mentioned and the output he wants to achieve is doable with a position fixed.. Am I sounding clear ?? - @Christoph

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48073/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-christoph)

Answer (score 1):

For stick you footer at the bottom you need to make it `position:fixed` `bottom:0;` and add `margin-top:(height of your footer);`

```
#footer {
    background-color: #0082C0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 15px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin-top:30px; /* height of the footer */

}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/35rkG/)

Comment: Why are you guys so obsessed about fixed position? It's messy, error prone and absolutely not needed...

Comment: Can you please explain how it mess up so i would get to know what standard to follow ?

Comment: see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48073/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-christoph to follow my discussion with Nathan, I explained the problem there