# CSS position fixed bottom footer

Tags: css, footer, fixed

I am trying to fix my footer to the bottom, despite where I am on the page. I tried

```
.home-footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

but it only works if I take the footer outside of the body and position it right below the html element. How can I make this work while keeping it in the body?

*EDIT* I found the issue was that my body had `transform: translateX(0)`. That seemed to be conflicting with the fixed footer, because as soon as I got rid of that, it worked. However, I need that rule, or else my slide in navigation breaks.

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of your HTML and CSS in order to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue was a conflict between applying a transform to the body, and having a fixed footer. There appears to be an issue combining those two rules together like that. I resorted to using left positioning for my animation, rather than transform, and it fixed the issue. It's not ideal, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: THat pushes it to the bottom initially, but then when I scroll down, it doesn't scroll with the page.

Comment: I think the answer is here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189238/how-to-make-a-footer-fixed-in-the-page-bottom

Answer (score 0):

*Try this:*

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <footer>Your footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
// wrapper in your body, where your footer will be in
.container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 30px;
}

footer {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for. I want the CSS to always be visible on the screen, but the bottom. So, it will move as we scroll the page.

Comment: I updated my question. Basically it was an issue with transform being on the body, which seemed to conflict with the footer having position fixed.