# why is my footer not sitting on the bottom

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my footer is sitting slightly above the bottom of my webpage and not directly on the bottom

[image: Footer currently]

```css
h6 {
  font-family: Neue Haas Grotesk, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <h6>&copy; Alex Burger. All rights reserved<br>Further information can be requested through email.</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try `position:fixed` instead of `relative` ?

Comment: Maybe its because of your (h6) tag, try using another tag like (p, div or span)

Comment: Add your full code

Comment: You need to remove margins. Give `margin: 0`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/alex-burger/pen/aKBMZp

Comment: using position: fixed places it at the top of the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a footer fixed in the page bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189238/how-to-make-a-footer-fixed-in-the-page-bottom)

Comment: Removing the height:100% should work

Answer (score 2):

The `<h6>` tag has a native margin. So your problem will be solved with:

```
.footer h6 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Note that setting `margin: 0px` have not the result that you expect, this will only be solved changing other parts fo your document.