# Footer Div (navigation) jumps when scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a completly web-based app-looking layout.

My problem now is that the navigation makes a short jump when I let my S3 autoscroll to the topby dragging. If I scroll up normally (without releasing my finger) this problem does not occur.

It seems that there is a problem with fixed positioning and the regular browser-bar.

CSS:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    ..
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make it scroll over other div's or anything. A screen following div on the bottom or top of the screen usually does not work great without javascript, jquery, or a huge css.

anyway,

Have you tried putting the margin on

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Also giving it a specific size and/or height might help.

Did you try it cross browser?

Comment: Thanks for your replay!
Margin does not help.
Also I was not testing on with other browsers because it's enough for me if its not working on my device :P

Maybe I should use something like iScroll :/

Comment: I'm sorry. I just happened to stumble onto this though. I hope it helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123/css-fixed-to-bottom-and-centered