# make css footer stay under content

Tags: html, css

I have this css:

```
.lh_container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto 40px auto;
    position:relative;
}

.lh_footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;            /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}

.lh_footer-container {
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

and this HTML:

```
<div class="lh_container">

<div class="lh_footer">
    <div class="lh_footer-container">

    <div class="lh_footer_text">
    &copy; Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- container -->
```

but the footer will not stay at the bottom of the page - how can i achieve this?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123/css-fixed-to-bottom-and-centered

Comment: i have tried this - http://jsfiddle.net/cN8DQ/ - but still the same :(

Answer (score 3):

Use `fixed` instead of `absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/pnLyh/