# Simple way to add a buffer to the bottom of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single page app. `DIV` is absolute positioned. Content is ajax'd into this `DIV`. The content varies in length from a few hundred `px` height to 1500+px in height.

This container must remain absolute because I am using jQuery easing effects to preform content transitions.

**Problem is that the `DIV`is cut off at the bottom. I would like a buffer of 100px at the end of the content `DIV`.**

My idea is to use a relative `DIV` behind it with a negative z-index while using the height of the content `DIV` and adjusting by 100px plus to create a buffer.

Getting the height of content `DIV` doesn't seem to work. So I'm *getting the height of the document instead* *(maybe I'm doing *this* wrong?)*.

The problem with getting the height of the document is that it keeps growing on each iteration which is not the true length of the content `DIV`.

```
function adjustPageBottom() {
  var h;
  h = $(document).height();
  $("#pad_bottom").css( 'height', h+'px' );
}
```

So I decided to make an array which can store the previous height values:

```
var heights = [];
function adjustPageBottom() {
    var h, res;

    h = $(document).height();
    heights.push(h);

    switch (heights.length) {
      case 3:
        heights.shift();
      case 2:
        res = heights[1] - heights[0];
        break;
      case 1:
        res = heights[0];
        break;
    }
    $("#pad_bottom").css( 'height', res+'px' );
}
```

This approach works but I'm not ecstatic about it. I need a simpler solution. How can I do this? Perhaps pure CSS or other simple alternatives exist? Please give recommendations. Or perhaps optimize my code? Thanks.

Comment: why didn't you try `margin-bottom:100px` or ` padding-bottm:100px` for the absolute div

Comment: Have you tried `#content { padding-bottom: 100px; }` or `body {padding-bottom: 100px;}`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do yet? You're trying to stick the thing to the bottom?  There are several examples here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123/css-fixed-to-bottom-and-centered

Comment: When you are reading and distributing the returned data, could you just append "x" blanks (&nbsp;) to the end of the data that would give you 100px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a relative positioned `DIV` beneath the absolute positioned content `DIV` and dynamically update the height of the relative `DIV` based on the `scrollHeight` of page. This gives the desired effect and works beautifully.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="page_buffer" style="position:relative; z-index:-1;"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function adjustPageHeight() {
  $('#page_buffer').css('height','1px'); // important reset:
    // reset buffer height before recalculating the scrollHeight
  var h = $(document.body)[0].scrollHeight;
  $('#page_buffer').css('height',h+'px');
}
```